# Angular: how to give visual/UI cue when change to component happened?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

Another Angular newbie challenge...

Let's say I have an app that shows the most recent price of an AAPL stock. I have a component to which this price is passed. Every time I query API, I get a new price and pass it to a component.

The problem:

I want to give some visual feedback to a user staring at the app. Let's say I want to quickly flash some background-color on a price that was just updated and gracefully fade it away.

How do I make this happen?

Thanks in advance for any possible solutions!

Comment: Look at animation chapter in official guide of angular

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/animations - just adding the direct link. I think animations is the way to go for this.

Answer (score 1):

Simple implementation

```
//Component
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list'
})
export class ListComponent {
  private color: string;

  apiGet(){
    this.color = ""//Get color from API
  }

  getColor(): string {
    return this.color;
  }
}

Template
<div style='background-color:{{getColor()}}'>List</div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I don't know what you were thinking :) but this doesn't work. This `get`s a colour for initial render. I was talking about getting a colour for when change detection and update happens.

Comment: There is a difference between assigned a variable and assigning a method.. assigning a method gets the value updated dynamically

Comment: Oh I see how you mean. Whenever I get some input value from parent component, I can somehow detect it and use that event to trigger some different colour.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution here:

Angular 5 Animations: increment and decrement

https://medium.com/xp-inc/angular-5-animations-increment-and-decrement-12bb6aa992eb?